# Free Vertices in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

[image]How can we program this kind pf permutations in GAP?

Let we have and Extended Triangle Group $(2,3,7)=<x^2=t^2=y^3=(xt)^2=(yt)^2=(xy)^7=1>$

We have subgroup of Index 14 having permutation representation

$x=(3,4)(5,7)(6,8)(9,12)(10,13)(11,14)$

$y=(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,9,10)(8,11,12)$

t is the axis of symmetry in the Coset Digram as cited above

I want to find the *i* free vertices of this group means points fixed for *x* and moved for *y*, but are contiguous.

Here in this example points 1 and 2 are fixed for x and moved for y, moreover are consecutive to each other.

So here we have *i=2* free vertices.

How can I program this in GAP.

I am starting like this

```
>FreeVertices := function(p,q,r,n)
>local x,t,y,f,g,m,hlist,h,j,k,o,l,permslist,perms,points;
>f := FreeGroup(3);
>g := f/[f.1^p,f.2^2,f.3^q,(f.1*f.2)^2,(f.2*f.3)^2,(f.1*f.3)^r];
>h := Filtered(LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup(g,n),i->Index(g,i)=n);
>points:=[];
>o := [];
>m:=[];
> x := List(CosetTable(g,h[1]){[1]},PermList)[1];
> t := List(CosetTable(g,h[1]){[3]},PermList)[1];
> y := List(CosetTable(g,h[1]){[5]},PermList)[1];
>Print("x =",x,"\n","y =",y,"\n","t =",t,"\n");
>for j in MovedPoints(y) do
>if j=j^x then 
>Add(points,[j,j^x]); #Collection of Points in y that are fixed for x.
>fi;
>od;
>Print("Points =",points,"\n");
>k:=Length(points);
>for m in points do
>l:=m^y;
>Add(o,l); # finding the images of the previous list under y 
>od;
>Print("Points fixed for x and their images under y =",o,"\n");
>end;
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "consecutive points in a group", please? Also, give an example of valid values of arguments p,q,r,n for you function.

Comment: The line `if j` seems to be incomplete. Otherwise, it will not work since `j` must be boolean.

Comment: I am writing in GAP code for j but I dont know why it is not showing here. However, when you will press edit you can see what I have written. I have written >if j<j^y and j=j^x then >Add(Points,[j,j^y]);

Comment: Here p,q,r are the values of the Triangle Group (p,q,r)=<x^p=y^q=(xy)^r=1> and n is the Index of the subgroup of Triangle Group.

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting - one should use four spaces to mark the code. Now it is properly displayed. Had no time to study it, but one remark is that the line after `return points` will not be executed. It may help to write comments in your code to explain what are you doing.

Comment: No, please give some valid numerical values of p,q,r,n that are four input parameters for your function, so the reader who'd like to experiment with it could test it with meaningful input. I presume that `p,q,r` should be some particular numbers, since you take some fixed positions from the coset table? (the latter is doubtful anyway, since you take same positions for each `h` and rely that they are 1st, 3rd and 5th for each call). Also note that the loop over `h` finishes early, so after that your `x,t,y` are those from the last iteration.

Comment: @ Alexander, it is hard for me to give particular values for some (p,q,r). But to make this question easier I write this like as follows that what I am trying to do in GAP. Let G is the group having permutation x=(1,2,3)(4)(5)(6,7)(8)(9,10,11)) and y:=(4,5,8,10)(1,3,2,6) this group has index 11. Here I want GAP to find cycle(4,5,8) that lies cycle of y permutation (4,5,8,10)  that each of these is fixed for x but moved for y and in consective i.e (these points lie in a cycle of y fixed for x and next to each other. means 4->5->8 .

Comment: Could you please try to rewrite the question to make it more comprehensible and focussed on the particular problem you want to solve here? Also, I find "consecutive" to be a very misleading term. In addition, points actually do not belong to the group - they belong to the action domain. Anyhow, it seems to me like you can program this in terms of functions from [the manual chapter on permutations](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap42.html).

Comment: Hmm... In terms of permutation groups, without looking at coset diagrams: do you mean that you have a group $G$, generated by $x$ and $y$, and you need to calculate the subset $M$ of `MovedPoints(G)` consisting of points fixed under the permutation $x$, and then calculate images of points from $M$ under the permutation $y$?

Comment: P.S. You last edit again causes misformatted code. You have to indent each line of the code with four spaces, like I did in my earlier revision today. Otherwise some lines are displayed as nonsense.

Comment: Thats right. Moreover, the images of points from M under permutation y should contain in one cycle.

Comment: One more bit: what about the order of the images of points then?

Comment: You mean to say order of cycle structures of their images? I think this doesn't matter, because we are looking their images under y that contatin in single cycle of y. I am really sorry for the inconvinience that I am having difficulty to explain as far as I could do.

Comment: So it looks to me like the order of images matters, since you want points which are fixed by the first permutation follow one another in the 2nd.

Comment: Thats right, For instance if I have a permutation representaion x:=(4,5)(7,6); and y is (3,2,1,5,4)(6,8,9,7,10) I want the result in these permutation (3,2,1),(8,9),(10) as they are consecutive in y and similar in order as in y and fixed for x.

Comment: However, still yet I couldn't work with it in GAP.

Comment: try to debug the code posted recently in the GAP Forum, I think that would be the right way. Use only fixed points instead of moved points to speed that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that I've got right the question boiled down to two permutations, and you will be able to incorporate this example in your code. I am not commenting those parts of the question which are outside that scope, but please check my concerns about `CosetTable` usage expressed in the comments. If this example does not do what you had in mind, or if you need further comments, please ask.

---

**Question (short version)**

Let $G$ be a permutation group acting on the set $S$, and let $G$ is generated by two permutations $x$ and $y$. Let $M$ be the subset of $S$ consisting of points fixed under the permutation $x$. How to calculate images of points from $M$ under the permutation $y$ and then check that $M^y$ contains in some cycle of $y$?

**Answer**

First, two permutations from one of your comments:

```
gap> x:=(1,2,3)(6,7)(9,10,11);                            
(1,2,3)(6,7)(9,10,11)
gap> y:=(4,5,8,10)(1,3,2,6);                              
(1,3,2,6)(4,5,8,10)
```

Now calculate which points from `[1..11]` are fixed under `x` (we obtain 11 as the maximum of the largest moved points of `x` and `y`, so we don't actually need a group generated by these elements):

```
gap> xfixes:=Filtered([1..Maximum(List([x,y],LargestMovedPoint))],i->i^x=i);
[ 4, 5, 8 ]
```

Indeed, it is not obvious from the GAP manual how to convert a permutation into a list of cycles. One could write one's own code for that, but perhaps the following trick would be faster:

```
gap> ycycles:=CyclesOfTransformation(AsTransformation(y));
[ [ 1, 3, 2, 6 ], [ 4, 5, 8, 10 ], [ 7 ], [ 9 ] ]
```

(Note that `CyclesOfTransformation` is not available in GAP 4.6 and earlier releases).

Now we can check whether there is a cycle which involves all points from a given subset:

```
gap> ForAny(ycycles, c -> IsSubset(c,xfixes)); 
true
gap> ForAny(ycycles, c -> IsSubset(c,[1,2,3]));
true
gap> ForAny(ycycles, c -> IsSubset(c,[1,4]));  
false
```

So, this works correctly. Now we are ready to calculate the images of elements of `xfixes` under `y`:

```
gap> xy:=List(xfixes, a -> a^y);
[ 5, 8, 10 ]
```

And even check in the same way as before that `y` has a cycle which involves 5, 8 and 10:

```
gap> ForAny(ycycles, c -> IsSubset(c,xy));   
true
```

But actually this last step is not needed, since if there is a cycle containing all points from `xfixes`, then clearly this cycle will also contain their images.

Comment: Thanks, glad that it helps. Perhaps the original question may be shortened too to get rid of some downvotes. In particular, the picture does not self-explain the  next line "can we program this kind pf permutations in GAP?" and at least rotating it would be nice.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I am very sorry I couldn't convey my question perfectly earlier. But this answer finds me fruitful. Could you please tell me how to get guidance in GAP forum? Should I have to email my questions over their on forum@gap-system.org?

Comment: @smaz: yes, and to be able to post to the Forum, first you have to subscribe via http://mail.gap-system.org/mailman/listinfo/forum

Comment: when I am writing CyclesOfTransformation(AsTransformation(y)) its giving me an error. Except this AsTransformation(y) is working but giving me the list of permutations in single list.

Comment: @smaz: could you show me examples which reproduce these problems, please?

Comment: y:=((1,3,4)(5,7,8));
(1,3,4)(5,7,8)
gap> n:=CyclesOfTransformation(AsTransformation(y));
Error, Variable: 'CyclesOfTransformation' must have a value

Comment: AsTransformation is given in Reference manual, however, I could not find CyclesOfTransformation in it. This is why I think GAP is not identifying it

Comment: @smaz: Could it be that you're using an older version of GAP? The latest is GAP 4.7.4, and code for transformation changed a lot since GAP 4.6.

Comment: Yes you are right I am using 4.6.5.

Comment: @smaz: as of today, GAP 4.7.5 is the latest release: http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/